# is there any column click event in ext js?

Tags: events, extjs, click

I am using Ext.grid.gridpanel.As in rowclick event, we can handle row click of grid..Is there any event to handle column click of grid?

i want to select a particular column of grid.

Answer (score 6):

There is no special `columnclick` event on the gridpanel or the selection model, but you can listen to the

```
cellclick : ( Grid this, Number rowIndex, Number columnIndex, Ext.EventObject e )
```

event on the gridpanel itself - irrespective which selection model you use. Looking at the `columnIndex` you'll know which column has been clicked. If you want to react on clicks onto the header row, use the `headerclick` event instead.

Comment: Too bad you can't name the column and check the name. If you move the column you have to change the index. Bad design by ExtJS.

Comment: @MarcoSulla True. ExtJS 6 provides a `Ext.grid.CellContext` which works around this specific problem.