# Ext JS - Cell with multiple values, with "list" of combo boxes

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using the Ext JS Grid component, and I've got the following fields (along with their datatypes):

```
ID (int)
Name (string)
Foods (List<string>)
```

As defined, there can be multiple Foods per user, and each food is selected from an existing Food DataStore. Displaying the Food list in the cell is easy; I just use a custom renderer. The potentially complicated part is editing those foods.

Whenever a user edits the Foods cell, I'd like a combo box to appear for each food item, populated from the Foods DataStore. I'll also need the user to be able to add/delete Food items, which means I'll need a small form of some sort.

Could anyone tell me the best way to accomplish this? I've perused the documentation on Ext JS (though perhaps not well-enough), but I was unable to find a good solution. I'm still fairly new to it.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,

B.J.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be to take editing functionality out of your grid and use it only to show data. you can edit them easily with a `Ext.msg` popup shown after `rowclick` or `rowdblclick` event had been fired. inside `Ext.msg` you can use some html tags.

you can also follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537347/is-there-any-column-click-event-in-ext-js) to learn about capturing `cellclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this, but without being able to add/delete items.

In your grid, you'll want to set the editor for the column in question to a combobox. I don't think you'll need to bother with changing the renderer at all, the combobox should take care of it for you.

```
xtype: 'grid',
store: Ext.create('MySite.store.UserStore'),
columns: [
    { header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id' },
    { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
    {
        header: 'Foods', dataIndex: 'foods', minWidth: 200,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            store: Ext.create('MySite.store.FoodStore'),
            valueField: "food",
            displayField: "food",
            editable: true,
            maxHeight: 150,
            width: 310,
            multiSelect: true
        }
    }
],
selType: 'cellmodel',
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    })
]
```

The store that populates the grid (I called mine UserStore here) will need to use a type of 'auto' for the List field.

```
Ext.define('MySite.store.UserStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'UserStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id', 'name', { name: 'foods', type: 'auto' }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: // your data provider
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    }
```